# Remove A Specific Instance of a Partially Duplicated Entry In a List In Python 3

Tags: python, list, duplicates, match, partial

I am relatively new to Python. However, my needs generally only involve simple string manipulation of rigidly formatted data files. I have a specific situation that I have scoured the web trying to solve and have come up blank.

This is the situation. I have a simple list of two-part entires, formatted like this:

```
name = ['PAUL;25', 'MARY;60', 'PAUL;40', 'NEIL;50', 'MARY;55', 'HELEN;25', ...]
```

And, I need to keep only one instance of any repeated name (ignoring the number to the right of the ' ; '), keeping only the entry with the highest number, along with that highest value still attached. So the answer would look like this:

```
ans = ['MARY;60', 'PAUL;40', 'HELEN;25', 'NEIL;50, ...]
```

The order of the elements in the list is irrelevant, but the format of the ans list entries must remain the same.

I can probably figure out a way to brute force it. I have looked at 2D lists, sets, tuples, etc. But, I can't seem to find the answer. The name list has about a million entries, so I need something that is efficient. I am sure it will be painfully easy for some of you.

Thanks for any input you can provide.

Cheers.

alkemyst

Comment: I read it as "ignoring the number for the purposes of uniqueness, keeping it for the purposes of determining the highest and for output"...

Comment: That makes sense @sabik.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best data structure for this would be a dictionary, with the entries split up (and converted to integer) and later re-joined.

Something like this:

```
max_score = {}
for n in name:
    person, score_str = n.split(';')
    score = int(score_str)
    if person not in max_score or max_score[person] < score:
        max_score[person] = score

ans = [
  '%s;%s' % (person, score)
  for person, score in max_score.items()
]
```

This is a fairly common structure for many functions and programs: first convert the input to an internal representation (in this case, split and convert to integer), then do the logic or calculation (in this case, uniqueness and maximum), then convert to the required output representation (in this case, string separated with `;`).

In terms of efficiency, this code looks at each input item once, then at each output item once; there's unlikely to be any approach that can do better than that (certainly not formally, and likely not in practice). All of the per-item operations are constant-time and fast. It accumulates the intermediate answer in memory (in `max_score`), but again that is unavoidable; if memory is an issue, the input and output could be changed to iterators/generators, but the whole intermediate answer has to be accumulated in `max_score` before any items can be output.

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm. Thank you so much  @sabik.